# Handlebars.Net.Helpers in MSbuild project with no cs

Tags: c#, msbuild, handlebarshelper, handlebars.net

I did some extensive research but I couldn't find similar problem.
I drop in some project which is based on MSbuild it only have csproj file and bunch of handlebars templates that are created during build.

My problem is that handlebar.net.helpers do not support If equal sting1 string2.
I did found lot of examples hot to create one but problem is that when I create new cs file and add new helper during build it still say that specific helper does not exist which tell me that it either not compile or most likely I mess up.

Do you have any idea how to add new helper when I don't have any cs file?

I did try to create new simple c# file as library because I only need one helper and maybe more in the future :-)
What I didn't try is to create from scratch new project because that project is part of larger one so I do not want to mess up.
Dont know if I should create C# with main function if that would help... Really dont know

Comment: Can you please specify what the custom extension logic is you are looking for?